# Sending parameters to contentComponent of Drawer Navigator from outside the navigator

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I have a Screen in which I embed a DrawerNavigator.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { GlobalNavigator } from "../navigators/globalNavigator";

export default class GlobalScreen extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.doSomething= this.doSomething.bind(this);
    }

    doSomething() {
        // do something
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <GlobalNavigator doSomething={this.doSomething} />
        );
    }
}
```

I have a Drawer Navigator in which I specify "contentComponent".

```
import React from "react";
import { DrawerNavigator } from "react-navigation";
import MainScreen from "../screens/mainScreen";
import MenuContent from "../components/menuContent";

export const GlobalNavigator = DrawerNavigator(
    {
        Main: {
            screen: MainScreen
        }
    },
    {
        drawerWidth: 350,
        drawerPosition: "left",
        initialRouteName: "Main",
        backBehavior: "initialRoute",
        contentComponent: props => <MenuContent {...props} />
    }
);
```

I want to send from the screen a parameter to navigator so that I can pass it to "contentComponent". How can I achieve this? I tried with "screenProps" but this is not present in the "props": `contentComponent: props => <MenuContent {...props} />`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1.store the GlobalScreen instanse

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { GlobalNavigator } from "../navigators/globalNavigator";

var globalScreen = undefined;

export default class GlobalScreen extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        globalScreen = this;
        this.doSomething= this.doSomething.bind(this);
    }

    doSomething() {
        // do something
    }

    //param to contentComponent
    param = {abc:'123'};
    someMethod = ()=>{ 
         //code
    };

    render() {
        return (
            <GlobalNavigator doSomething={this.doSomething} />
        );
    }
}
```

2.give contentComponent a method props to get the globalScreen

```
export const GlobalNavigator = DrawerNavigator(
    {
        Main: {
            screen: MainScreen
        }
    },
    {
        drawerWidth: 350,
        drawerPosition: "left",
        initialRouteName: "Main",
        backBehavior: "initialRoute",
        contentComponent: props => <MenuContent getMainScreen={() => {return globalScreen;} } {...props} />
    }
);
```

3.in MenuContent

```
let globalScreen = this.props.getMainScreen();
let param = globalScreen.param;//param you want to pass to menuContent
globalScreen.someMethod();//method in globalScreen
```

achieve,but not very elegant....